# Unable to share images in android project chat applicaton

Tags: java, android, firebase

I tried to share the image in my chat application. But was not able to successfully share it. It's selecting the image from the gallery but not appearing in the Userchat screen and not getting upload in the firebase also.

I am not able to find the solution for it. I would very much appreciate if someone can help me out.

```
    attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                    {
                      "Image", "Documents"
                    };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserChatActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select File");

            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        checker = "image";

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 438);
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        checker = "pdf";
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

**StorageReference**

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 438 && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        fileUri = data.getData();

        if (!checker.equals("image"))
        {

        }
        else if (checker.equals("image"))
        {
            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Image Files").child(fAuth.getUid());;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The shared code has no error. The functionality of the above code is its picking up the image from the gallery. The thing I am getting stuck is that the image I am selecting is not showing in the user chat and not getting upload in cloud storage.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the right (correct) URL?

Comment: That what I want to know. Is I am doing it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to log the value, to see if it's indeed the right one?

Answer (score 1):

**Store that image URL in your chat.**

You can do something like this, I am giving you an example for firebase realtime database:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 438 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            // you should show some progress dialog or progress bar here for better user experience.
            progressDialog.show()
            fileUri = data.getData();
            if (checker.equals("image")) {
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Image files");

                final String messgSenderRef = "Messages/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/" + userId;
                final String messgReceiverRf = "Messages/" + userId + "/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference messageRef = databaseReference.child("Messages").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(userId).push();
                final String messagePushId = messageRef.getKey();
                final StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child(messagePushId + "." + "jpg");
                filepath.putFile(fileUri).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                 // you can show progress of upload here, let suppose you have a progressDialog then:-
                        double p = ((double) 100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                        progressDialog.setMessage((int) p + "%" + " Uploading....");

                    }
                }).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();


                        }

                        return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            // Now you have Uri of your image
                            downloadUri = task.getResult().toString();


                            Map<String, Object> messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
                            messageTextBody.put("message", downloadUri);
                            messageTextBody.put("name", fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
                            messageTextBody.put("type", fileStatus);
                            messageTextBody.put("from", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            messageTextBody.put("to", userId);
                            messageTextBody.put("messageId", messagePushId);
                            messageTextBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                            messageTextBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);


                            Map<String, Object> messageBodydetails = new HashMap<>();
                            // add message to sender and receiver's 
                            messageBodydetails.put(messgSenderRef + "/" + messagePushId, messageTextBody);
                            messageBodydetails.put(messgReceiverRf + "/" + messagePushId, messageTextBody);


                            databaseReference.updateChildren(messageBodydetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        editText.setText("");
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        }

                    }
                });

            } else {

            }


        }

    }
```

Then in the chat you can check for the changes in the database in realtime and update your chat's recycler view in realtime. Just specify the chat message type to identify and display the view accordingly. If the chat type is text, show the text message. If the chat type is an image, load an image from the URL you have stored.

Comment: I have to make changes in xml also. Right?

Comment: Yes, @RAndroid, you have to change your chat item layout to make it such so that it can show both images and text according to the message type.

Comment: Ok I will add.
I am getting an error.
**Error: User does not have permission to access this object.**

Comment: Is their any source that I can share Screenshot.